# Does this use of Singleton make sense

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

I use a Singleton in my project. Does my code make sense? Specifically this line:

```
public UserRepository User => new UserRepository();
```

`UserRepository` implements functions such as add, edit and delete by reflection.

```
internal sealed class DataManager
    {
        public UserRepository User => new UserRepository();

        private static DataManager _active = null;
        private static object _syncRoot = new object();

        public static DataManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_syncRoot)
                    if (_active == null)
                        _active = new DataManager();
                return _active;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using an expression bodied property will create a new UserRepository every time a get is made for the property. Is that what you want?

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking *"what does this line of code do?"* or if you're asking *"does it ever make sense to always return a new instance of a class from a property?"*. Please clarify what you mean by *"is there a sense in this code?"*

Comment: @JonathonChase No, I want the opposite)

Comment: Except instead of doing all of that code, which ranges from unnecessary to harmful, just have an initialized variable and be done with it.  `public static DataManager Instance {get;} = new DataManager();` is all you need to have a superior implementation than you have here.

Comment: @RufusL So the effect would be the same without Singleton?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What you've shown us is a `static` get-only property that is only ever set to one instance of it's type, and the other is a get-only instance property that always returns a new object. What *specifically* are you trying to do? What do you want?

Comment: Your code will create new instance of `UserRepository` class every time it is accessed at runtime. If you want only one instance then you can create property with public get and private set. And set the property to new instance in the constructor.

Comment: It sounds like you want `public UserRepository User {get;} = new UserRepository();`, but I'm still a bit unclear. This will make the property readonly and instantiate only once.

Comment: @JonathonChase so if I do as you've shown, there will only be one copy, right?